# Cardboard Mockup Scene for Hololens Look and Fell

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, hololens

I didn't know which forum to ask about this is the most fitting, but I think this is the best:

Our designers want to check their stuff on the hololens. For example to check if their gui is right and how the depth effect is. But we dont have that many hololenses and the developer don't have the time to load up the designers' projects for checking.

So my question is:
Is there an plugin or Scene, in which they can load their stuff and export/build it for vr (cardboard or at least htc vive) and have the same look and feel like the holo lens (just with a 3d world?). It's mostly for some fancy 3D iron man Style ui (for now).

A concrete Problem:

They have a animated loading Circle(s). They want to check if you look straight on it at the holo lens or if you have a to big perspective distortion or occlusion. Also it would be nice if the small FOV would be simulated.

I'm kinda searching a hololens vr simulator for unity scene/script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry for the long silence (had other Stuff to do):

The other answering Persons have good Solutions, but i just want to make an Overview of things that helped me on the way. When I asked the questions i had the Hololens like 3 Days and no Idea of it:

Checking Clipping/Lost of sight:
Set the Camera FOV to 55 the aspect ratio to 16:9. Also if you import the Camera from the Toolkit you can change the eye from the Settings. Also set the Clipping Plane to 0.75. Objects closer than this will only be shown on one eye.

As Dtb49 said: "use he Holographic Remoting App on your HoloLens.  Once you do that in the Unity editor you can go to Window->Holographic Emulation->Remote To Device and type in the IP address displayed when you launch the app from your HoloLens." The Problem is you need the Fall Creators Update for that (and your Admin won't let you update). And it's very laggy (in my case)

Or use the emulator as Gambolati said.

Last but not least my favorite way now: Use the "Manual Gaze Control" Script from the Toolkit and attach to the cam and use the "Input Manager Prefab". The EditorHandsInput is needed. No you can emulate interactions in the Playmode.

PS: To check the 3D Experience Cardboard is not usefull. It's just another experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can also view your project on the HoloLens without deploying it by getting the **Holographic Remoting App** on your HoloLens. Once you do that in the Unity editor you can go to Window->Holographic Emulation->Remote To Device and type in the IP address displayed when you launch the app from your HoloLens. Then you click the connect button in the editor. Now, when you hit play in the editor it will run on your HoloLens with out the need to deploy it to your HoloLens.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a "port" to try on a CardBoard.

You can try the [Hololens Emulator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install_the_tools). I think that for that you want, it's must works.

Also, you can try to run the scene onto Unity3D.